XmlListModel doesn't support query with index in Qt 6
I am trying to adapt a qml application for Qt 6.
The application uses XmlListModel.
In Qt6, XmlRole has been replaced by XmlListModelRole.
In Qt5, I can use the construct:
query: “/Keyboard/Row[” + (rowIndex + 1) + “]/Key”.
But in Qt6 it doesn't work.
Why?
XML file I use.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Keyboard>
    <Row>
        <Key labels = "q|1" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "w|2" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "e|3" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "r|4" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "t|5" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "y|6" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "u|7" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "i|8" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "o|9" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "p|0" ratio = "1"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key labels = "a|%`~" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "s|^|" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "d|*\" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "f|{+" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "g|}-" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "h|[=" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "j|]_" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "k|()" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "l|&apos;&quot;" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "/|?" ratio = "1"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key labels = "⇑!shift" ratio = "1.5" checkable = "true"/>
        <Key labels = "z|@" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "x|$" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "c|!" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "v|;" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "b|:" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "n|&lt;" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "m|&gt;" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "⌫!backspace" ratio = "1.5"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key labels = "123!source:keyboard_num.xml" ratio = "1.5"/>
        <Key labels = "Us!source:keyboard_ru.xml" ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = " |" ratio = "5"/>
        <Key labels = ".|," ratio = "1"/>
        <Key labels = "↵!enter" ratio = "1.5"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>

This is the code for Qt5:
Column {
    id: column
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Repeater {
        id: rowRepeater
        model: XmlListModel {
            source: root.source
            query: "/Keyboard/Row"
        }

        Row {
            id: keyRow
            property int rowIndex: index
            anchors.horizontalCenter: if(parent) parent.horizontalCenter

            Repeater {
                id: keyRepeater
                
                model: XmlListModel {
                    source: root.source
                    query: "/Keyboard/Row[" + (rowIndex + 1) + "]/Key"

                    XmlRole { name: "labels"; query: "@labels/string()" }
                    XmlRole { name: "ratio"; query: "@ratio/number()" }
                    XmlRole { name: "icon"; query: "@icon/string()" }
                    XmlRole { name: "checkable"; query: "@checkable/string()" }
                }

                Key {
                    id: key
                    width: keyWidth * ratio
                    height: keyHeight
                    iconSource: icon
                    mainFont: proxyMainTextItem.font
                    mainFontColor: proxyMainTextItem.color
                    secondaryFont: proxySecondaryTextItem.font
                    secondaryFontColor: proxySecondaryTextItem.color
                    keyColor: root.keyColor
                    keyPressedColor: root.keyPressedColor
                    bounds: root.bounds
                    isChekable: checkable
                    isChecked: isChekable &&
                               command &&
                               command === "shift" &&
                               allUpperCase

                    property var command
                    property var params: labels

                    onParamsChanged: {
                        var labelSplit = params.split(/[|]+/)

                        mainLabel = params.split(/[!|]+/)[0].toString();
                        if (labelSplit[1]) secondaryLabels = labelSplit[1];
                        command = params.split(/[!]+/)[1];
                    }

                    onClicked: {
                        if (command)
                        {
                            var commandList = command.split(":");

                            switch(commandList[0])
                            {
                                case "source":
                                    root.switchSource(commandList[1])
                                    return;
                                case "shift":
                                    root.allUpperCase = !root.allUpperCase
                                    return;
                                case "backspace":
                                    root.keyClicked('\b');
                                    return;
                                case "enter":
                                    root.enterClicked()
                                    return;
                                case "tab":
                                    root.keyClicked('\t');
                                    return;
                                default: return;
                            }
                        }
                        if (mainLabel.length === 1)
                            root.emitKeyClicked(mainLabel);
                    }
                    onAlternatesClicked: root.emitKeyClicked(symbol);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is correct result.

This is the code for Qt6 I try to make:
Column {
    id: column
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Repeater {
        id: rowRepeater
        model: XmlListModel {
            id: rowModel
            source: root.source
            query: "/Keyboard/Row"
        }

        Row {
            id: keyRow
            property int rowIndex: index
            anchors.horizontalCenter: if(parent) parent.horizontalCenter

            Repeater {
                id: keyRepeater
                
                model: XmlListModel {
                    id: keyModel
                    source: root.source
                    query: "/Keyboard/Row/Key"

                    XmlListModelRole { name: "labels"; elementName: ""; attributeName: "labels"}
                    XmlListModelRole { name: "ratio"; elementName: ""; attributeName: "ratio" }
                    XmlListModelRole { name: "icon"; elementName: ""; attributeName: "icon" }
                    XmlListModelRole { name: "checkable"; elementName: ""; attributeName: "checkable" }
                }

                Key {
                    id: key
                    width: keyWidth * ratio
                    height: keyHeight
                    iconSource: icon
                    mainFont: proxyMainTextItem.font
                    mainFontColor: proxyMainTextItem.color
                    secondaryFont: proxySecondaryTextItem.font
                    secondaryFontColor: proxySecondaryTextItem.color
                    keyColor: root.keyColor
                    keyPressedColor: root.keyPressedColor
                    bounds: root.bounds
                    isChekable: checkable
                    isChecked: isChekable &&
                               command &&
                               command === "shift" &&
                               allUpperCase

                    property var command
                    property var params: labels

                    onParamsChanged: {
                        console.log("params", params)
                        var labelSplit = params.split(/[|]+/)

                        mainLabel = params.split(/[!|]+/)[0].toString();
                        if (labelSplit[1]) secondaryLabels = labelSplit[1];
                        command = params.split(/[!]+/)[1];
                    }

                    onClicked: {
                        if (command)
                        {
                            var commandList = command.split(":");

                            switch(commandList[0])
                            {
                                case "source":
                                    root.switchSource(commandList[1])
                                    return;
                                case "shift":
                                    root.allUpperCase = !root.allUpperCase
                                    return;
                                case "backspace":
                                    root.keyClicked('\b');
                                    return;
                                case "enter":
                                    root.enterClicked()
                                    return;
                                case "tab":
                                    root.keyClicked('\t');
                                    return;
                                default: return;
                            }
                        }
                        if (mainLabel.length === 1)
                            root.emitKeyClicked(mainLabel);
                    }
                    onAlternatesClicked: root.emitKeyClicked(symbol);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is wrong result.


If I'm not mistaken, the module Qt XML Patterns is deprecated, and Qt 6 doesn't support it. Based on what is shown in the source, the query is only parsed by separating the slash (/) character, and no index is processed.

It would be nice if you could crop your images so they don't take up too much vertical space. Also, the Key here is undefined. The code can be much shorter and currently does not meet the [MRE] requirements.
